# What does the following UDP connection mean?

Tags: udp

What does the following entry mean? 
Is that mean someone has connected to the server from this IP or somthing else?

```
Nov 23 15:33:54 www-prod-2 snmpd[1573]: Connection from UDP: [66.151.147.194]:47011->[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:161
```

Comment: instead of down voting perhaps you could point out why this isn't a good question? it is very specific and I could use a little help.

Comment: This is meant to be a site for professional system administrators. This question does not show an understanding of the principles involved consistent with a professional system administrator thus the down votes.

Comment: Your question doesn't show any research attempt or basic understanding of what you are posting about. You are just posting a log entry, without any explanation or reference to any real problem whatsoever. You can edit your question to put some more information and background information and your problem.

Comment: It's not really a UDP connection. It's an SNMP connection, over UDP.

Comment: thansks bangal. I tried that yesterday with server info, what I had tried etc, but that also got down voted so I thought maybe something more specific would get a response.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a connection or connection attempt from ip 66.151.147.194 to the SNMP port of the Computer. SNMP uses Port 161 (TCP/UDP).

> Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) is a popular protocol for
>   network management. It is used for collecting information from, and
>   configuring, network devices, such as servers, printers, hubs,
>   switches, and routers on an Internet Protocol (IP) network.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776379%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

If you have no idea what it is, then you better check your server's configuration for SNMP service and make sure it is secured or properly configured.

Comment: Thank  you this is what I was looking for a direction to start researching.

Comment: You are welcome. You can just google for SNMP, or a combination with the Operating System you are using, you will surely find a lots of useful info.